# Slow connect to Google Cloud SQL Second Generation from App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm testing the new Google Cloud SQL Second Generation from an app using standard App Engine platform for PHP.

Both app and sql instance are in the same region, using 'any' as the cloud sql region (I can't find which zone is used by the App Engine project).

My initial tests are really disappointing: the connect to a second generation instance is 10x slower than a first generation instance. This are my results:

> AVG connect to Cloud SQL 1st Generation: 5 ms 880 µs
>
> AVG connect to Cloud SQL 2nd Generation: 62 ms 511 µs

Any ideas of this behaviour?

Comment: What's the connection string you use to connect to 1st and 2nd generation cloud sql instance respectively? Please also refer the doc on connecting cloudsql from appengine: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/

Comment: I'm using the right connection strings from the docs:
`/cloudsql/[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]`

Anyway, it has nothing to do with the connection string, as a Google Engineer said: https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/detail?id=137&thanks=137&ts=1462191679